# How to remove Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10

I just dont want any os in my my computer,  it is distracting me from my studies. Does anyone has an idea for removing ubuntu from a single boot.

Comment: You have a single boot and want to remove the one and only OS because it distracts you from your studies? How about locking away your Laptop/PC? After your exams you won't have to struggle to reinstall an OS.

Comment: although a reasonable suggestion, the OP is not asking for advice. It is up to said OP whether or not to take the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done from within a running operating system.

First of all ... backup all your personal data you want to keep.

1. Boot from Ubuntu installation media.
2. Select Try Ubuntu without installing.
3. Open GParted (partition editing tool).
4. Press the Windows key - type GParted.
5. Delete all partitions of the specific disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you can login into root console, type there `lsblk` to have a list of all your HDD (those without numbers are HDDS, those with numbers are sections of them). 
To erase any HDD or section, type 
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4M` where `/dev/sda` is the HDD you want to destroy.